# Debug Logs of Sites public user

Tags: debugging, force.com-sites

I searched this problem but the answer look out-dated. The org I'm working on has a public site (named 'Aste'). I am sure I could go to the debug logs and set a tracked user either with
'Aste' or 'Aste Profile Guest User'.
Since a couple of days this is no longer working, no error is given in the form where I put the name of the tracked user but when I see the debug-logs page nothing is there and nothing is logged.

Did something change about Sites debug-logs lately? Thanks very much for your assistance

T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to the Debug Logs issue known by Salesforce since Winter'14. I couldn't set up the debug logs for some users. Here is how to fix it : [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0DsAAK). It worked perfectly for me.